# Getting the lastest slug from url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, slug

This is my route:

```
Route::get('{slug?}/{slug2?}/{slug3?}', 'PageController@show');
```

This is how I got the slug value in my service provider:

```
$this->app->request->route('slug2')
```

Somethings my url looks like `base_url/slug` or `base_url/slug/slug2` or `base_url/slug/slug2/slug3`. I am looking for a laravel way to get the lastest slug always no matter how my url looks like. Is there a way to do that ?

Thx

Comment: I think with the way your route is defined you need to get the current url and then get the last part yourself.

Comment: @Andreas I know that my route is not the perfect solution . If you know a better way to do this , please post a solution . Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using this I can get the lastest slug from my url. But I am still looking for a better solution even If i have to change the route. This is the code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
....
Request::segment(count(Request::segments()))
```

Comment: I think this is the most sensible way of getting what's actually in the URL. Alternatively if your route is `show($slug = null, $slug2 = null, $slug3 = null)` you could do `$lastSlug = ($slug3?:($slug2?:$slug?:null))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode`

```
$url = base_url/slug/slug2/slug3;
$slugs = explode ("/", $url);
$latestslug = $slugs [(count ($slugs) - 1)];
```

Comment: with the explode,  thats the hardcoded way, I  am looking for a method or smth defined in Laravel to do this :)

Comment: Use public function getRouteKey()
{
    return $this->slug;
}
After back ()
See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects

Answer (score 0):

Though not an elegant method, this could work

```
$has_valid_slug = count($request->route()->parametersWithoutNulls());

if ($has_valid_slug) {

    $last_slug_key = key(array_slice($request->route()->parametersWithoutNulls(), 
                                     -1, 1, TRUE ));

    $last_slug = $request->route()->parametersWithoutNulls()[$last_slug_key];

}
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_parametersWithoutNulls